# JSON capacity, number of objects

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, json

How many objects can I send using a Json through Php?
In my android app I want to get the whole list of users which is in mysql, and now I only have some users, but if I have 10000 of users i would get all of them in this json?
Or which is the json´s capacity?

Thanks!! And sorry for my english!

Comment: There is no intrinsic limit. it depends on the structure you use to read / write it. as long as you use a Stream method, it's ok.

Answer (score 2):

PHP's `json_encode()` method doesn't have an inherit limit on how much data you can encode and send. It will come down to PHP memory limits on your server, the execution time of your script to do all this, and of course performance time to transmit all that to the phone.

Comment: Also possibly PHP's [max_execution_time](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no maximum capacity, however you have to keep in mind, that it may consume more memory on your phone than the may heap size, which leads to a `OutOfMemorryError`